# C++ exception syntax with ^

Tags: .net, managed-c++

I'm looking at a code file and see an catch statement in the following format:

```
try{
    do_something();
} catch (System::Exception^ e){
    log_something();
}
```

What is the significance of the ^ operator in the catch?

Comment: This is not C++

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875008.aspx

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/handle-to-object-operator-hat-cpp-component-extensions